# Beans should not be served with potatoes?

Tags: food-science, potatoes, beans, nutrient-composition, legumes

[Huffington Post writes:](https://www.huffingtonpost.ca/diana-herrington/pass-on-the-gas-7-ways-to_b_3080786.html)

> Potatoes conflict with digestion of the beans, so avoid eating them in the same meal.

Is this true? I couldn't find any reliable source.

Comment: At least half the claims in that article sound like "old wives tales" if not outright BS to me...